# Nexus repository not updated

Tags: nexus, maven-deploy-plugin

We upload artifacts to Nexus through the file protocol with Maven deploy plugin. Sometimes, those artifacts do not appear directly in Nexus Web interface. I have to do 'expire cache' and refresh the page. Moreover, this causes builds dependant of this artifact to fail.

I guess this is because, we deploy though file protocol. Is there a way to prevent this ? I saw the 'Not Found Cache TTL' in Nexus interface. Not sure to understand the doc. If I set this to zero, will this work ?

Thanks

PW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying directly to the file system should only be used in extreme cases such as bulk manipulations or imports. In order to make Nexus fully recognize the changes on disk, you would need to expire the cache and then you may have to rebuild the metadata. Both of these can be triggered from the repository screen. If you want the artifacts to be searchable, you would also have to fire off the indexer task as well.

All of those things happen automatically when you deploy via http/https directly to Nexus which is the way it is intended to be used

Comment: Thanks your complete reply !